# Como atualizar link sem refresh com javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Boa noite, existe alguma função que faz refresh em link âncora sem reload na página? Estou criando um sistema de curtir artigos, mas gostaria de criar uma forma de trocar o link "like" para "unlike. Tentei fazer um `location.href` mas a página atualiza o que eu não quero.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function add_like(id_artigo){

    $.post('php/add_like.php', {artigo_id:id_artigo}, function(dados){
      if(dados == 'sucesso'){

         get_like(id_artigo);

  }else{
        return false;
      }
   });
  }

function un_like(id_artigo, id_user){
   $.post('php/un_like.php', {artigo_id:id_artigo, user_id:id_user}, function(dados){
       if(dados == 'sucesso'){

       get_like(id_artigo);        
}else{

    return false;
}

});

function get_like(id_artigo){

  $.post('php/get_like.php', {artigo_id:id_artigo}, function(valor){

   $('#artigo'+id_artigo+'_like').text(valor);
});

}
</script>

   <?php
**$selLikes verifica se existe o like**

     $selLikes = getPhotoLiked($artigo_id, $user_id);  

       if($selLikes['num']==0){

     echo'<a class="like" onclick="javascript:add_like('.$artigo_id.');this.disabled=true" href="javascript:void(0)">like</a>';

    }elseif($selLikes['num']==1){

      echo'<a class="unlike" onclick="javascript:un_like('.$artigo_id.', '.$user_id.')" href="javascript:void(0)">unlike</a>';

   }

    ?>
```

Comment: Está faltando um `}` no final do `function un_like(id_artigo, id_user){`, só para lembrar. Veja o console (F12) da página. Seria melhor criar apenas uma chamada para curtir/descurtir, verificando  no client-side se existe ou não e removendo ou não.

Comment: @Inkeliz não é possivel criar um link que faz duas funções eu estou usando  onClick que chama funções diferentes

Comment: A necessidade é somente mudar o URL?

Comment: não @Inkeliz mudar o link ancora **<a>** ex assim que o usuario curte o artigo ele tem o direito de descurtir mas quero fazer isso sem refresh na página

Comment: Bem, "trocar o link like para unlike", em geral deseja que ao curtir a função seja trocada? Se eu curtir agora irei descurtir? Se for isto há outros jeitos melhores.

Comment: o mesmo método que o facebook usa like e deslike

Answer (score 3):

Você terá que usar `jQuery`. Use a função **$.ajax()**. Irei dar um exemplo básico

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="like_a" referencia="3" acao="like">Like</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("a#like_a").on('click', function(){

var acao = $(this).attr('acao');
var id_post = $(this).attr('referencia');

$.ajax({

url: 'arquivo_like_db.php',
type: 'POST',
data: {acao: acao, id: id_post},

success: function(callback){

if(acao == 'like'){
$(this).text('Unlike');
$(this).attr('acao', 'unlike');
}else{
$(this).text('Like');
$(this).attr('acao', 'like);
}

}
});
});
});
</script>
```

depois cria um arquivo chamado arquivo_like_db.php que captura `acao` e `id` via `$_POST` caso precise.

Estude sobre **$.ajax()** e **jQuery**, você irá conseguir o que precisa.

Comment: No caso ele já usa o JQuery, porque o `$.post()` é do JQuery.

Comment: @Alisson Acioli não existe essa tag referência no HTML

Comment: Qualquer tag pode ser criada. Se quiser  criar `Megatron = "Overpower"` pode criar. Depois pegar a o parametro `Megatron` via JQuery. Isso também vale para `<pudim class="chocolate"></pudim>`. ;)

Comment: @Inkeliz Ok, obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa dar reload, apenas mudar o url com o JQuery que já usa.

Modifique o botão para algo similar:

Para unlike:

```
<a class="unlike" idArtigo=''.$artigo_id.'" idUser = "'.$user_id.'">unlike</a>
```

Para like:

```
<a class="like" idArtigo=''.$artigo_id.'" idUser = "'.$user_id.'">like</a>
```

Desta forma você tem o parâmetro direto no `<a>`, com parâmetro personalizado contendo ambas as informações.

```
$('.unlike').click(function(){ // Quando clicar
un_like( $(this).attr('idArtigo') , $(this).attr('idUser') );  // Pega idArtigo e idUser e insere no un_like
$(this).switchClass('unlike', 'like'); // muda classe/funcao
$(this).text('like'); // muda nome
});

$('.like').click(function(){ //Quando clicar
add_like( $(this).attr('idArtigo') ); // Pega idArtigo e  inseri no add_like
$(this).switchClass('like', 'unlike'); // muda classe/funcao
$(this).text('unlike'); // muda nome
});
```

Acho que desta forma será mais fácil, entretanto deve efetuar algumas alterações para adaptar.

Isso pode ser uma ideia.